# Permanent sleep in the function of linux network driver?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver

In a linux network driver:

```
ssize_t device_read(struct file *file,char *buffer,size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
int i;
#endif
struct ed_device *edp;
DECLARE_WAITQUEUE(wait,current);
edp = (struct ed_device *)file->private_data;
add_wait_queue(&edp->rwait,&wait);
for(;;){

    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if ( file->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK)
        break;
    if ( edp->tx_len > 0)
        break;

    if ( signal_pending(current))
        break;
printk("Start going to sleep\n");
    schedule();
printk("return from scheduler\n");
}
set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
remove_wait_queue(&edp->rwait,&wait);

spin_lock(&edp->lock);

if(edp->tx_len == 0) {
     spin_unlock(&edp->lock);
     return 0;

}else
{...}
}
```

Once the function `read(fd_tx, tx_ptr, BUFFER_SIZE-1)` is called in a simple application, the kernel process `device_read` goes into sleep and info `Start going to sleep` is printed . It can never be awaked unless the application is ceased, then the info `return from scheduler` is printed.

Why the process cannot be awaked by `wake_up_interruptible(&ed[ED_TX_DEVICE].rwait)` in other function?